# Custom error handler in express.js is not called

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript, express, error-handling

I am setting up a simple express.js node server, and I can't seem to get my custom error handler to work. It seems like it isn't being called at all and instead some default express.js error handler is being called.

Note that this is in typescript, and uses mongodb, if that matters (don't think it should). Here is the relevant code:

index.ts:

```
import routes from './routes/index.ts';
import express, { Request, Response, NextFunction } from 'express';
// other imports...

type ServerErrror = {
    status: number;
    message: string;
}

const app = express();

// set up logging...

app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use('/', routes);
app.use((err: ServerError, req: Request, res: Response, next: NextFunction) => { // eslint-disable-line no-unused-vars
    console.error('in error handler');
    res.status(err.status).send(`got error: ${err.message}`);
});

mongoose.connect(MONGODB_URI)
    .then(() => {
        console.log('Successfully connected to database.');
        app.listen(SERVER_PORT, () => {
            console.log(`Server is up and running on port ${SERVER_PORT}`);
        }).on('error', error => {
            console.log('Error starting server:', error);
        });
    }, error => {
        console.log('Error connecting to database:', error);
    });
```

routes/index.ts:

```
import { Router } from 'express';
import dataRoutes from './data.ts';

const router = Router();

router.use('/data', dataRoutes);

export default router;
```

routes/data.ts:

```
import { Router } from 'express';
import Data from './models/Data';

const router = Router();

router.get('/', (_, res, next) => {
    Data.find((error, data) => {
        if (error) {
            console.log('found an error')
            next({ status: 500, message: 'got an error' });
            return;
        }
        res.send(`Got data: ${JSON.stringify(data.map(datum => datum.toJSON()))}`);
    });
});

export default router;
```

When I start the server and then send a GET request to the /data endpoint using postman, this is the output on the server:

```
Successfully connected to database.
Server is up and running on port 1234
found an error
GET /data 500 35.289 ms - 142 // this is from morgan logging
[object Object] // no idea where this is coming from, i assume express default error handler
```

And this is the return value i see in postman:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <title>Error</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <pre>[object Object]</pre>
    </body>
</html>
```

Again, not sure where this is coming from. I assume it must be the express default error handler.

Comment: can you `console.log(err)` in your error handler and see the structure

Comment: @naga-elixir-jar i already have a `console.error` there and it isn't ever called because it doesn't get there

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It turns out the problem was my use of [babel-preset-minify](https://github.com/babel/minify/tree/master/packages/babel-preset-minify) which apparently did not transform the code correctly. Getting rid of this preset made the code work with no other modifications.

Answer (score 2):

There are some problems with your code:

- `import routes from './routes/index.ts'` should not have the `*.ts` extension.
- `import dataRoutes from './data.ts';` should not have the `*.ts` extension.
- `ServerErrror` has one too many letters.

Here is short example that works on my machine. I removed the Mongoose-related code and changed the sample so that it is easy to reproduce in a single file. A call to `http://localhost:5000/data` returns `customErrorHandler > dataRoutes.get > Error`, which is I think what you require.

```
import { Request, Response, NextFunction } from 'express';
import bodyParser = require('body-parser');
import express = require('express');

type ServerError = {
  status: number;
  message: string;
}

const dataRoutes = express.Router().get('/', (_, res, next) => {
  setTimeout(() => { // mimic an asynchronous operation
    const error = true;
    if (error) {
      next({ status: 500, message: 'dataRoutes.get > Error' });
      return;
    }

    res.send('dataRoutes.get > Success');
  }, 1000);
});

const routes = express.Router().use('/data', dataRoutes);

const app = express();
app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use('/', routes);
app.use((err: ServerError, req: Request, res: Response, next: NextFunction) => {
  res
    .status(err.status)
    .send(`customErrorHandler > ${err.message}`);
});

app.listen(5000);
console.log('Now listening on port 5000');
```

This is my tsconfig.json file:

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "module": "commonjs",
    "allowSyntheticDefaultImports": true
  }
}
```

These are my package.json dependencies:

```
"devDependencies": {
  "@types/express": "^4.16.1",
  "typescript": "^3.4.1"
},
"dependencies": {
  "express": "^4.16.4"
}
```

Comment: I copy-pasted this code and ran it and it still doesn't call the custom error handler when i hit the endpoint. Can I ask what version of express you are using? (and body-parser, why not)

Comment: Sure. I added the package.json and tsconfig.json sections that might be of interest.

Comment: So, after much digging I have found the problem. I will create a separate answer for it since your post didn't give me the answer. However, I've upvoted your post/comment since it was helpful in guiding me during the debugging process.

Comment: For posterity: the errors you pointed out at the top of your post only exist in my post because I was trying to edit my actual code in order to make the code simpler for stackoverflow. They are not actual errors that I had to correct.

Answer (score 0):

In my case, I disable babel-preset-minify option `deadcode` and work well.

```
{
  "presets": [
    [
      "minify",
      {
        "deadcode": false
      }
    ]
  ]
}
```